# How can I resolve the return statement problem in python?

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

Since a function call (with return statement) in python, means that a variable (outside the function) can receive its value. But what we don't realize is that it actually calls the whole function, in place the function call is used? Even if you use a return statement.

Consider the following code -

```
def fnx():
    
    a = 0
    print("Hello! I'm function.")
    a = 2 + 4
    return a

val = fnx()

print("\n 2 + 4 =",val)
```

Its output -

```
Hello! I'm function.

 2 + 4 = 6
```

The problem with its working is, when you only want the value of variable a in variable val, the print statement of the function should not be passed in place of the function call for its returnable value.
Can you tell me a way ,a method, a module etc. (except 'global'), that can only assign the return variable, while not passing the whole function in the place of the function call?

Comment: the `print("Hello! I'm function.")` is NOT AT ALL passed into variable `a`, remove `print("\n 2 + 4 =",val)` and you'll see it is still there. That is very unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: It is not passing the whole function call : it just executes the lines, then return what is given by `return`

Comment: I want just the returned value, not the whole execution of the function, while function call.

Comment: Remove `print("Hello! I'm function.")` ? there is no other way. You call a method : all of its code is ran, so its print are executed

Comment: I feel like there's a misunderstanding here about what a function is.  The point of calling fnx() is to make the entire function run.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. See [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: That's true. But if you have a function that prints the input message, & stores its value to a variable, & returns it. Then, another function calls the previous function, only for its return variable, which is to be used further in that function. Should an input message be displayed the second time, asking what it asked previously. It will be very inappropriate. If there was a way to use that passed value only, while avoiding the display of the same input message, twice.

Comment: Thank you, for acknowledging me a member of the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fnx(print_message = True):

    a = 0
    if print_message:
        print("Hello! I'm function.")
    a = 2 + 4
    return a


val = fnx()

print("\n 2 + 4 =",val)

val = fnx(print_message = False)

print("\n 2 + 4 =",val)
```

Output:

```
Hello! I'm function.

 2 + 4 = 6

 2 + 4 = 6
```

The second call to the function explicitly states it doesnt want the message in the function. The technique is known as *setting flags.*